# Does a standard structure of JUnit tests exist? How many assertions per test are usually prefered?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I will explain this better with an example:

Imagine I have a function that receives an array of X integers and an extra integer that contains a starting position, it calculates the average value for 10 numbers in the array starting from that position, but ignores `0` values and returns `-1000000` if the array doesn't contain 10 or more values from the starting position to the end:

```
public double calculateAverage(ArrayList<Integer>, int startingPosition){
    //functionLogic
    return myAverage;
}
```

I am new to unit testing, but I would suggest doing the following tests here:

- Test with a 20 integer list and `5` as starting position. (should return the average value of the 10 numbers from `5` to `14`)
- Test with a 20 integer list and `15` as starting position. (should return `-1000000`)
- Test with a 9 integer list. (should return `-1000000`, no matter the starting position)
- Test with a 20 integer in which half of the numbers are `0` and 5 as starting position. (should return the average of numbers between `5` and `14` without counting `0`s).
- Test with a 20 integer in which half of the numbers are `0` and 15 as starting position. (should return `-1000000`)

*This tests might be not enough, or too many, or simply bad tests, please, feel free to comment on any improvement, as I am sure most of you know more about unitary tests than I do*.

**My question:**

Do I have to write 5 different JUnit test functions? Is it better to write only 1 with 5 assertions? Or do I dive it (for example) in groups of 2 and 3?

What's the recommended style here?

Thank you all for your patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty broad, but I think the "informal" consensus is to absolutely **limit** the number of asserts within tests.

In other words: you prefer many small tests over few huge tests.

Reasoning: the core idea of unit tests is to help you understand (and then fix) the root cause of failures. And when you have multiple asserts or "tests" within one test method, then you spend your first minutes to understand where exactly that test is failing.

Compare that to a test that contains just two or three lines (some setup followed by an "execution" followed by an verification/assert step).

Beyond that: there is a lot of good material out there, for example by [javacodegeeks](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-best-practices/).

Comment: This was just an example, but in reality I currently have a 500 line class that has 36 unit tests right now, and I don't even cover 100% of the code. Is that normal?

Comment: That sounds ... a lot. But that could have plenty of reasons; for example your core class is already doing too many different things (violating the single responsibility principle). In that sense: you probably put that code on codereview.stackexchange.com and see what people have to say. Unit test coding skills, as any kind of coding skills can only improve when you do reviews. The more the better.

Comment: I just saw the edit and the link, thanks for sharing, it gives some really specific advices, exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: It's a class that works as "Common", so every function that is used in many other places goes here as static. (This includes average of 10 numbers, average of 3, check if X numers are multiple of Y number, check if an string contains X character.....) a lot of simple math problems that are used in many other classes.

Comment: For such kind of math problems, there might be **better** ways of testing; maybe something around https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck could bee of help here. In other words: instead of specifying input/output yourself, you let the runtime **search** for values that "break" the test.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion, I will take a look at that too.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to write a lot of test methods you can go for **Parameterized Test**.  
 where you will have only one test method, and a set of inputs and corresponding output.

read more about parameterized test at [parameterized tests in action](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm).